# merge_asof() not returning values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames:

```py
data = {'w_s': ['w','s','w', 's'],
        'date': ['01/17/2023', '03/05/2023','02/04/2023','03/30/2023']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and

```py
data2 = {'w_s':['w','w','s','s'], 
        'begin_date':['01/14/2023','01/28/2023','03/01/2023','03/15/2023'],
        'end date': ['01/26/2023', '02/05/2023', '03/14/2023','04/01/2023'],
        'week no': [1,1,4,4]}
```

that look like this:

```
df1
  w_s        date
0   w  01/17/2023
1   s  03/05/2023
2   w  02/04/2023
3   s  03/30/2023

df2
  w_s  begin_date    end date  week no
0   w  01/14/2023  01/26/2023        1
1   w  01/28/2023  02/05/2023        1
2   s  03/01/2023  03/14/2023        4
3   s  03/15/2023  04/01/2023        4
```

The Problem:

I am trying to merge these two tables based on two conditions:

- the w_s value in df2 must match a row in df2 (w = w, s = s) - this will match several lines, so also:
- the date value in df1 must fall in between the begin and end date

Desired Output:

```
desired_output
  w_s        date  week no
0   w  01/17/2023        1
1   s  03/05/2023        4
2   w  02/04/2023        1
3   s  03/30/2023        4
```

My Attempt: I was thinking a merge_asof() would work. The default is a 'backwards' look, so theoretically, it would look backward from the nearest end date?

```
desired_output = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='date', right_on='end date', by='w_s', allow_exact_matches=False)
```

The code completes, but returns blank values in the merged columns (df2).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your example returns 2 filled rows from `df2` for me. With `direction="forward"` all rows are filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a simple left `merge` then `query` to filter the rows which satisfy the interval condition

```
(
    df1
    .merge(df2, how='left')
    .query('`begin_date` <= date <= `end date`')
    .drop(columns=['begin_date', 'end date'])
)
```

Result

```
  w_s        date  week no
0   w  01/17/2023        1
2   s  03/05/2023        4
5   w  02/04/2023        1
7   s  03/30/2023        4
```